# generate pdf file from itext and upload it to server in android

Tags: android, retrofit, slim

I am creating pdf file using itext in android and after that i am passing the pdf file path to a method to store it in server. But its not working, i am using retrofit and slim framework.

```
final String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date);
     File file_path= new File(pdfFolder + "/" + timeStamp + ".pdf");


File file = new File(file_path.toString());
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("pdf", file.getName(), requestFile);
    if(isNetworkAvailable(context)){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<LoginResult> call = service.upload(body);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResult> call, Response<LoginResult> response) {
               String post_message = response.body().getMessage();
               view.hideProgressDialog();
               Toast.makeText(context,post_message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResult> call, Throwable t) {
               view.hideProgressDialog();
               view.networkError();
            }
        });


    }else{
        view.hideProgressDialog();
        view.networkError();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to create the PDF on the server? Also: once you have the PDF on your Android system, your question "how to send it to the server" is no longer an iText-specific server. Sending a file to a server doesn't depend on the software that was used to create the file.

Comment: ya you are right. i will try to create the PDF on the server. Thanks

Comment: I just solve the problem and I am not creating PDF on server.

Comment: Great for you. You should post your solution.